# Raphael: Bring obscured dots to front

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've got a bunch of Raphael circle objects on a canvas, in many cases they overlap and sometimes a smaller circle is completely covered by a larger circle sitting on top of it. In cases like these I'd like to bring the smaller circle forward when it is moused over--or more accurately, when the coordinates it contains, are moused over.

I've been experimenting with the getElementsByPoint() method as part of a mousemove handler, but am finding its performance to be really sluggish.

Any tips or tricks for bringing covered or obscured dots forward on a Raphael canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an overlay mask as a transparent `rect`, covering the entire canvas area, that contains each shape's path coordinates, and attach the shapes to it as handlers.

for this you will need to create custom events for the overlay mask to fire and for shapes to catch, let's call them "`shape-coor-over`" and "`shape-coor-out`".

this mask will act as a mediator: it will listen to mouse moves and will fire `shape-coor-over` and `shape-coor-out` custom events upon certain conditions (if mouse has entered a path's area etc.), and when the registered shapes are notified, their handlers will call the shape's `toFront()` or `toBack()`, accordingly.